# Jquery library conflict with another jQuery library

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, jquery-events, mapmyindia-api

I am using a lot of jQuery libraries in my application.

My application is based on a map, and the map is generated by my own server mapmyindia.com.

The problem is that there is a jQuery conflict that occurs when I use fancybox jQuery library, pagination jQuery library and drop-down checklist jQuery library, all work together.

My direction search API's don't work because of a jQuery library conflict.

However, if I remove all the jQuery libraries, I can use my direction search API 
 just fine.

With the jQuery libraries enabled, it gives me an error:

> $.jsonp is not a function

My application is on app.mapmyindia.com/michelin  please help me.......

```
<script>MIREO_RESOURCES_ROOT = "http://46.137.254.191/MapServer/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://46.137.254.191/MapServer/MireoWebMap.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = $("#map");
    var valid = new Validation();
    map.MireoMap();
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/ui.dropdownchecklist-1.4-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.0.6" media="screen"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

use jquery noconflict and wrap your code in jQuery functions :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($){
  // my code here each 
});
```

good luck.

Comment: thanks its working on chrome and internet explorer but not woking on mozilla it genrate en error like $.jsonp is not a function..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jquery `noConflict()` and download the latest version of jquery that resolve some problems conflict

Comment: thanks its working on chrome and internet explorer but not woking on mozilla it genrate en error like $.jsonp is not a function..

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you have declared your javascript, that is importing your MapmyIndia Js first, using it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = $("#map");
var valid = new Validation();
map.MireoMap();
</script>
```

& then calling jQuery, I don't think so jQuery would be creating problem.

Also you should be using

```
var map=document.getElementById("id");
```

since you are calling jQuery after that so $() won't work.

EDIT : Or if the MayMyIndia Js also requires jQuery then you should call jQuery.Js on top.

Comment: thanks MayMyIndia Js is embedded with jquery js. thanks my problem is resolved now.......thanks again